# Change appearance of equation numbers locally

Tags: equations, numbering, appendices

In the MWE below, I would like to have the `equation numbers` in the Chapter "Appendix" (but only there!) being displayed as follows:

(A.1), (A.2), (A.3) ...

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}          
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}       
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{prop}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{XY}

\begin{prop}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}
\end{prop}

\begin{appendices}

\newtagform{WithA}{(A}{)}              
\usetagform{WithA}                     
\newcommand{\Aref}[1]{(A\ref{#1})}     

\renewcommand\thechapter{}                                          

\makeatletter                                                       
\def\chaptermark#1{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp. \  #1}}{}}   
\makeatother                                                        

\chapter{Additional stuff nobody is interested in}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]                                       
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{1em}{}                        
\titlespacing*{\section}                                            
  {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}                            
\titlecontents{section}[1.5em]                                      
  {}{}{}{\titlerule*[7.5pt]{.}\contentspage}                        

\begin{prop}\label{y}
\begin{equation}
      a+b=c
\end{equation}
\end{prop}
Equation (\ref{x}) in Proposition \ref{y} is nice.  
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I have edited my example --> It now produces the desired output, but it doesn't seem to be very elegant! A major drwaback of my solution is that I am bound to forget to use `\Aref` insted of `\ref` when referring to equations in the appendix. Hence a solution which does this automatically would be highly appreciated!

Hence, I modify my question to: Are there any **better** solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
```

after `\begin{appendices}`. You'll be able to use `\ref` or `\eqref`.

Comment: Thx! Exactly what I was looking for. I have now added a proposition (see edited question) and tried the same thing for the proposition numbering (it should be "Proposition A.1" in the appendix instead of "Proposition .0.2") but I wasn't successful. How would I have to adjust your solution for proposition numbers?

Comment: You could also write in the preamble `\let\oldappendices\appendices` then `\def\appendices{\def\theequation{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}\oldappendices}` which may be "too TeX" and "not enough LaTeX" of an answer...

Comment: Adding `\setcounter{prop}{0}\renewcommand{\theprop}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{prop}}` solves the proposition numbering problem. Only, why do I have to reset the prop counter?? Without `\setcounter` the Proposition in the Appendix gets number even though A.2 it's the first proposition in the appendix chapter??

Answer (score 6):

Do it with the `appendix` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}
\appendix
%\addappheadtotoc
%\appendixpage
\appendixpageoff
\chapter{Appendix}
\begin{equation}
  a+b=c
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details run `texdoc appendix` from command prompt.

Comment: In fact, I do use the `appendix` package already. I have edited my question to show you what I am actually doing (wanted to keep the example as short as possible). The problem with your solution is that I do not want to have the A after Appendix in the title! I would prefer to let everything as it is and only insert some code which gets me the A into the equation numbers. It's not actually an appendix problem.